# How to change filename and extension while downloading a text file from data uri

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When i download a data uri(this works in chrome/FF),using

```
url1 = "data:attachment/plain;base64,encodeuri(<base64data-xyz>)"
```

Here using attachment mime type forces it to download, using any other mime type like(text/html) will open the content of file in new tab, since i wanted to download ,i used attachment/plain-xyz [MIME type].

I tried the download attribute, but everytime,the file name downloaded is "download", and there is no extension, so it gets appeneded in my downloads folder as ".FILE", whereas i need to store it using "variable.txt"

Please do guide me how you are able to change "download.FILE" to some "variable.txt", i have tried all attributes of data, download, data-downloadurl, contentdisposition,even tried setting pom attributes etc..

Please help in converting the downloaded file content to a file with some filename and .txt as extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)** provides easy ways to handle these

Answer (score 0):

```
// Sanitizing the filename:
$filename = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\-\_\.]/i','',$_POST['filename']);

// Outputting headers:
header("Cache-Control: ");
header("Content-type: text/plain");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
```

or thisk link may be helpful
[http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html][1]

Comment: Question was about JS, not PHP.